# Parallax cuts image in menu

Tags: javascript, image, parallax

I have a problem with my parallax function [here](http://www.betavivo.se/products/viktstart/)
The function itself works great, but whenever I scroll down to where a parallax image is (for example on one of the product pages), and at the same time hover over the top menu products, it makes the images disappear. From what I know, it only occurs in Chrome.

I know for sure it's the parallax function, because if I delete the parallax mirror div, it all works great again.

Have anyone experienced the same thing, or has a clue of why it's doing like this, please let me know!

EDIT: Hi, Here's a jsfiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/fxL7yq35/7/

```js
/*!
 * parallax.js v1.3.1 (http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)
 * @copyright 2015 PixelCog, Inc.
 * @license MIT (https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
!function(t,i,e,s){function o(i,e){var h=this;"object"==typeof e&&(delete e.refresh,delete e.render,t.extend(this,e)),this.$element=t(i),!this.imageSrc&&this.$element.is("img")&&(this.imageSrc=this.$element.attr("src"));var r=(this.position+"").toLowerCase().match(/\S+/g)||[];return r.length<1&&r.push("center"),1==r.length&&r.push(r[0]),("top"==r[0]||"bottom"==r[0]||"left"==r[1]||"right"==r[1])&&(r=[r[1],r[0]]),this.positionX!=s&&(r[0]=this.positionX.toLowerCase()),this.positionY!=s&&(r[1]=this.positionY.toLowerCase()),h.positionX=r[0],h.positionY=r[1],"left"!=this.positionX&&"right"!=this.positionX&&(this.positionX=isNaN(parseInt(this.positionX))?"center":parseInt(this.positionX)),"top"!=this.positionY&&"bottom"!=this.positionY&&(this.positionY=isNaN(parseInt(this.positionY))?"center":parseInt(this.positionY)),this.position=this.positionX+(isNaN(this.positionX)?"":"px")+" "+this.positionY+(isNaN(this.positionY)?"":"px"),navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)?(this.iosFix&&!this.$element.is("img")&&this.$element.css({backgroundImage:"url("+this.imageSrc+")",backgroundSize:"cover",backgroundPosition:this.position}),this):navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)/)?(this.androidFix&&!this.$element.is("img")&&this.$element.css({backgroundImage:"url("+this.imageSrc+")",backgroundSize:"cover",backgroundPosition:this.position}),this):(this.$mirror=t("<div />").prependTo("body"),this.$slider=t("<img />").prependTo(this.$mirror),this.$mirror.addClass("parallax-mirror").css({visibility:"hidden",zIndex:this.zIndex,position:"fixed",top:0,left:0,overflow:"hidden"}),this.$slider.addClass("parallax-slider").one("load",function(){h.naturalHeight&&h.naturalWidth||(h.naturalHeight=this.naturalHeight||this.height||1,h.naturalWidth=this.naturalWidth||this.width||1),h.aspectRatio=h.naturalWidth/h.naturalHeight,o.isSetup||o.setup(),o.sliders.push(h),o.isFresh=!1,o.requestRender()}),this.$slider[0].src=this.imageSrc,void((this.naturalHeight&&this.naturalWidth||this.$slider[0].complete)&&this.$slider.trigger("load")))}function h(s){return this.each(function(){var h=t(this),r="object"==typeof s&&s;this==i||this==e||h.is("body")?o.configure(r):h.data("px.parallax")||(r=t.extend({},h.data(),r),h.data("px.parallax",new o(this,r))),"string"==typeof s&&o[s]()})}!function(){for(var t=0,e=["ms","moz","webkit","o"],s=0;s<e.length&&!i.requestAnimationFrame;++s)i.requestAnimationFrame=i[e[s]+"RequestAnimationFrame"],i.cancelAnimationFrame=i[e[s]+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||i[e[s]+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];i.requestAnimationFrame||(i.requestAnimationFrame=function(e){var s=(new Date).getTime(),o=Math.max(0,16-(s-t)),h=i.setTimeout(function(){e(s+o)},o);return t=s+o,h}),i.cancelAnimationFrame||(i.cancelAnimationFrame=function(t){clearTimeout(t)})}(),t.extend(o.prototype,{speed:.2,bleed:0,zIndex:-99999,iosFix:!0,androidFix:!0,position:"center",overScrollFix:!1,refresh:function(){this.boxWidth=this.$element.outerWidth(),this.boxHeight=this.$element.outerHeight()+2*this.bleed,this.boxOffsetTop=this.$element.offset().top-this.bleed,this.boxOffsetLeft=this.$element.offset().left,this.boxOffsetBottom=this.boxOffsetTop+this.boxHeight;var t=o.winHeight,i=o.docHeight,e=Math.min(this.boxOffsetTop,i-t),s=Math.max(this.boxOffsetTop+this.boxHeight-t,0),h=this.boxHeight+(e-s)*(1-this.speed)|0,r=(this.boxOffsetTop-e)*(1-this.speed)|0;if(h*this.aspectRatio>=this.boxWidth){this.imageWidth=h*this.aspectRatio|0,this.imageHeight=h,this.offsetBaseTop=r;var n=this.imageWidth-this.boxWidth;this.offsetLeft="left"==this.positionX?0:"right"==this.positionX?-n:isNaN(this.positionX)?-n/2|0:Math.max(this.positionX,-n)}else{this.imageWidth=this.boxWidth,this.imageHeight=this.boxWidth/this.aspectRatio|0,this.offsetLeft=0;var n=this.imageHeight-h;this.offsetBaseTop="top"==this.positionY?r:"bottom"==this.positionY?r-n:isNaN(this.positionY)?r-n/2|0:r+Math.max(this.positionY,-n)}},render:function(){var t=o.scrollTop,i=o.scrollLeft,e=this.overScrollFix?o.overScroll:0,s=t+o.winHeight;this.visibility=this.boxOffsetBottom>t&&this.boxOffsetTop<s?"visible":"visible",this.mirrorTop=this.boxOffsetTop-t,this.mirrorLeft=this.boxOffsetLeft-i,this.offsetTop=this.offsetBaseTop-this.mirrorTop*(1-this.speed),this.$mirror.css({transform:"translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)",visibility:this.visibility,top:this.mirrorTop-e,left:this.mirrorLeft,height:this.boxHeight,width:this.boxWidth}),this.$slider.css({transform:"translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)",position:"absolute",top:this.offsetTop,left:this.offsetLeft,height:this.imageHeight,width:this.imageWidth,maxWidth:"none"})}}),t.extend(o,{scrollTop:0,scrollLeft:0,winHeight:0,winWidth:0,docHeight:1<<30,docWidth:1<<30,sliders:[],isReady:!1,isFresh:!1,isBusy:!1,setup:function(){if(!this.isReady){var s=t(e),h=t(i);h.on("scroll.px.parallax load.px.parallax",function(){var t=o.docHeight-o.winHeight,i=o.docWidth-o.winWidth;o.scrollTop=Math.max(0,Math.min(t,h.scrollTop())),o.scrollLeft=Math.max(0,Math.min(i,h.scrollLeft())),o.overScroll=Math.max(h.scrollTop()-t,Math.min(h.scrollTop(),0)),o.requestRender()}).on("resize.px.parallax load.px.parallax",function(){o.winHeight=h.height(),o.winWidth=h.width(),o.docHeight=s.height(),o.docWidth=s.width(),o.isFresh=!1,o.requestRender()}),this.isReady=!0}},configure:function(i){"object"==typeof i&&(delete i.refresh,delete i.render,t.extend(this.prototype,i))},refresh:function(){t.each(this.sliders,function(){this.refresh()}),this.isFresh=!0},render:function(){this.isFresh||this.refresh(),t.each(this.sliders,function(){this.render()})},requestRender:function(){var t=this;this.isBusy||(this.isBusy=!0,i.requestAnimationFrame(function(){t.render(),t.isBusy=!1}))}});var r=t.fn.parallax;t.fn.parallax=h,t.fn.parallax.Constructor=o,t.fn.parallax.noConflict=function(){return t.fn.parallax=r,this},t(e).on("ready.px.parallax.data-api",function(){t('[data-parallax="scroll"]').parallax()})}(jQuery,window,document);
```

```css
/* P A R A L L A X */


.parallax-fullwidth {
    height: 550px;
    background: transparent;
 position:relative; 
 overflow:hidden !important;
}

.parallax-fullwidth .two-column-left,
.parallax-fullwidth .two-column-right {
 padding: 50px 10%;
 width: 35% !important;
 text-align: center;
 min-width: 300px}

.parallax-mirror {
 /*overflow: hidden !important;*/
 overflow: visible !important;}
 

/* MENU */


.sub-navigation {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #f1efeb;
 padding: 0px 10%;
 width: 80%;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 padding-top:55px;
 height: 60px;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;}

.sub-holder,
.nav-holder {
 text-align: left;
 display:inline-table;
 margin-left: 0px;
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover,
.nav-menu li:focus > a,
.nav-menu li a:focus,
.sub-menu li:hover > a,
.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu li:focus > a,
.sub-menu li a:focus {
 // set animation
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;}

.sub-navigation .sub-menu li {
 text-align: left;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin: 0px !important;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 3px 2px 7px;}
 
.main-navigation .nav-menu li {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 8px 0px 0px;
 height: 45px;
 padding: 10px 0px 3px;}
 
.main-navigation .nav-menu li.main-item {
 padding: 10px 3px 3px;}
 
.sub-navigation .sub-menu li a {
 font-size: 12px;}

.sub-navigation .sub-menu li a:hover {}
 
 
.sub-navigation .sub-menu li:hover {
 background: #e3e1dc;}

.sub-navigation .navigation-link,
.main-navigation .navigation-link {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 8px;
 float: left;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 }
 
.sub-navigation .back,
.main-navigation .back {
    -moz-transition-duration:.4s;
    -o-transition-duration:.4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.4s;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height:0;
    width:100%;}

.sub-navigation:hover div.back,
.main-navigation:hover div.back {
    height:250px;}
 
ul.sub-menu,
ul.nav-menu {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    width: 100% !important;
    position:relative;}
 
ul.sub-menu li,
ul.nav-menu li {
    float:right;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
 line-height: normal !important;}
 
ul.nav-menu li {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top: 7px;}
 
ul.sub-menu li > a,
ul.nav-menu li > a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
    display:table-cell;
 vertical-align: bottom;
    padding:0 6px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.active {
color:#a2a09c !important;}

ul.sub-menu li > a {
 height: 50px;}

ul.sub-menu li a img,
ul.nav-menu li a img {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
 bottom: 0px;
}

.subs {
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    width:100%;
 font-size: 16px;
 visibility: hidden;
   opacity:0;
 height: 0px;
 text-align: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 transition: height 0.5s ease 0s,visibility 0s 0.3s,opacity 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s,visibility 0s 0.3s,opacity 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s,visibility 0s 0.3s,opacity 0.3s;
 -o-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s,visibility 0s 0.3s,opacity 0.3s;
}

.main-navigation .subs {
 top: 55px;}

.sub-menu > li:hover > .subs,
.nav-menu > li:hover > .subs {
    background: #e3e1dc;
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 height: 450px !important;
 
 // set animation
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
 -o-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.subs > .subs-content {
 padding: 4% 8%;
 opacity: 0;
 
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.2s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.2s;
 }

.subs-content .icon-description {
 margin-top: 10px !important;} 
 
.icon-description {
 margin-top: 30px;}
 
.icon-description h4 {
 margin: 0px !important;}

 
.sub-menu > li:hover > .subs .subs-content,
.nav-menu > li:hover > .subs .subs-content {
 opacity: 1;}
 
 
.subs > .subs-content > .subs-column {
 float: left;
 width: 49%;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 20px;}
 
.subs-column img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 470px}
 
.subs > .subs-content > .subs-column-right {
 float: right;
 width: 46%;}

.sub-menu li div.subs dl,
.nav-menu li div.subs dl {
    -moz-transition-duration:.2s;
    -o-transition-duration:.2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.2s;
    float:left;
    margin:0 130px 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:40px 0 5% 2%;
    width:0;
}
.sub-menu dt,
.nav-menu dt {
    color:#fc0;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:700;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.sub-menu dd,
.nav-menu dd {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left;
}
.sub-menu dd a,
.nav-menu dd a {
    background:transparent;
    color:#fff;
    height:20px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:80px;
}
.sub-menu dd a:hover,
.nav-menu dd a:hover {
    color:#fc0;
}
.sub-menu li:hover div.subs dl,
.nav-menu li:hover div.subs dl {
    -moz-transition-delay:0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay:0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.2s;
    margin-right:2%;
    width:21%;
}
ul.sub-menu li:hover > a,
ul.sub-menu li > a:hover,
ul.nav-menu li:hover > a,
ul.nav-menu li:hover > a {
    color: #a2a09c;
}

ul.sub-menu li:hover:after,
ul.nav-menu li:hover:after {
 background: url(../images/sub_hover.png);
 width: 33px;
 height: 20px;}

.sub-menu li:hover div.subs,
.sub-menu li a:hover div.subs,
.nav-menu li:hover div.subs,
.nav-menu li a:hover div.subs {
    width:100%;
}


 
.nav-menu .sub-item {
 min-width: 10px !important;
 margin-top: 0px !important;
 padding: 4px 0px 6px !important;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;}
 
.nav-menu .sub-item a {
 height: 46px;}
 
 
.nav-menu .sub-item:hover {
 background: #e3e1dc;}

.js .nav-menu {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
} 

.nav-menu.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="sub-navigation">
            <div class="navigation-content">
    <ul class="sub-menu slide">
            <li><a href="/products/viktstart/"><img src="http://betavivo.se/wp-content/themes/betavivo/images/Betavivo_ViktStart_icon_small.png" class="img_left" /><span class="navigation-link">Betavivo <br />
<span class="viktstart-text">vikt>start</span></span></a>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div class="subs-content">
                                <div class="subs-column">
                                    <img src="http://betavivo.se/wp-content/themes/betavivo/images/Betavivo_ViktStart_icon.png" />
                                    </div>
                        <div class="subs-column-right"><h2>Betavivo <br>
          <span class="viktstart-text">vikt>start</span></h2>
                         <p>Betavivo vikt>start är ett kosttillskott med glukomannan som bidrar till viktminskning.</p>
                         <a href="/products/viktstart/" class="button orange">Läs mer</a>
                         <div class="clear"></div>
                                        <div class="icon-description">
                          <img src="http://betavivo.se/wp-content/themes/betavivo/images/icon_weightloss.png" class="icon_left" />
                         <div style="overflow:hidden;">
                                        <h4>Viktminskning</h4>
                         <small>Glukomannan bidrar till viktminskning i samband med intag av en energibegränsad kost.</small>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                    
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
   </nav>
            hej
            <div class="parallax-fullwidth animatedParent" data-position="top" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0.5" data-bleed="10" data-image-src="http://betavivo.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Viktstart.jpg" data-natural-width="2000" data-natural-height="1333" data-position="0px 0px"></div>
```

Comment: can you make a code example to demo our problem? Ideally use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and provide an example that's as [minimal as possible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't see any parallax effect on your website, so I don't see any problems (on Chrome/MacOs).

Comment: I can see parallax on http://betavivo.se/products/viktstart/, but no problem on my Chrome/FF/MacOs. Can you provide more information on your Chrome version / OS ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments! I have chrome version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) on a Mac-computer... weird that it's behaving like this on my computer but not on your :S

Comment: No one else experiencing the same thing as I do?? Would be soo grateful if you could please have a look!